# Firestore forEach returns one item

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a project / to-do appliction with firestore.
I want to return all the current projects where the active user has been assigned to.

In a `console.log(doc.id, doc.data())`, I get the two projects where he has been signed up for.
But when I want to show them both on the home screen, I only see one project.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong
Anyone that can help me?

My function:

```
const returnProjects = async () => {
  const list = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#projectList');
  const projects = query(collectionGroup(db, 'projects'));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(projects);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const deadline = doc.data().Deadline;
    const fireBaseTime = new Date(
      deadline.seconds * 1000 + deadline.nanoseconds / 1000000,
    );
    const formatOptions = {
      format: 'dd MMM  yy', 
    };
    console.log(doc.id, '>', doc.data());
    const newElemement = document.createElement('div');
    if (list) list.appendChild(newElemement).setAttribute('class', 'projectCard');
    const card = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('.projectCard');
    if (card) { card.innerHTML = `
    <h4>${doc.id, doc.data().Name}</h4>
    <p>${fireBaseTime.toLocaleDateString('eng-BE', formatOptions)}</p>
    <span>3</span>
    `; }
  });
};
```

my Html:

```
    <main>
      <div id="dashboard" class="dashboard">
        <div class='dashboardUtils'>
          <h3 id="dashboardName"></h3>
          <span id="currentDate"></span>
        </div>
        <button id="editDashboard" class="secondary-button"></button>
      </div>
      <div id='dashboardEdits-form' class="editOpen">
        <form id='dashboardEdits' class='edit-form'>
          <div id='practicalDisplayname'>
            <label for='displayname' class='form-label'>Username</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-input' id="displaynameInput" name='displayname'></input>
          </div>
        </form>
        <button id="confirmEdits" class="secondary-button">Save edits</button>
      </div>
      <div id='amountMessage'>
        <h1 id='amountProjects'></h1>
      </div>
      <div id='projectList'></div>
    </main>
```

A screenshot:
[image: console.log returns two projects but renders one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *for each document* in the results you do:

```
const card = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('.projectCard');
if (card) { card.innerHTML = `
<h4>${doc.id, doc.data().Name}</h4>
<p>${fireBaseTime.toLocaleDateString('eng-BE', formatOptions)}</p>
<span>3</span>
`; }
```

While you're creating a new project card for each result, the `querySelector` always returns the **first** card for the HTML. From the MDN documentation on [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> An Element object representing the first element in the document that matches

So for the second document, you're replacing the `innerHTML` that you set for the first document.

---

To solve the problem, since you already have a reference to the element you just generated, add the `innerHTML` to that instead of looking it up with a query selector:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  ...
  const newElement = document.createElement('div');
  if (list) list.appendChild(newElemement).setAttribute('class', 'projectCard');
  newElement.innerHTML = `
  <h4>${doc.id, doc.data().Name}</h4>
  <p>${fireBaseTime.toLocaleDateString('eng-BE', formatOptions)}</p>
  <span>3</span>
  `; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is caused by the following behavior:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#:~:text=The%20appendChild()%20method%20of%20the%20Node%20interface%20adds%20a%20node%20to%20the%20end%20of%20the%20list%20of%20children%20of%20a%20specified%20parent%20node.%20If%20the%20given%20child%20is%20a%20reference%20to%20an%20existing%20node%20in%20the%20document%2C%20appendChild()%20moves%20it%20from%20its%20current%20position%20to%20the%20new%20position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#:%7E:text=The%20appendChild()%20method%20of%20the%20Node%20interface%20adds%20a%20node%20to%20the%20end%20of%20the%20list%20of%20children%20of%20a%20specified%20parent%20node.%20If%20the%20given%20child%20is%20a%20reference%20to%20an%20existing%20node%20in%20the%20document%2C%20appendChild()%20moves%20it%20from%20its%20current%20position%20to%20the%20new%20position).

What this means is that appendChild will remove the node if already present in the DOM, which is what we are seeing here. This can be easily solved by creating a deep clone of the node first using cloneNode, before appending it to the target div.

Comment: You should provide details about the link, site and page title since links can break. Eg see 'Node.appendChild()' under References --> Web APIs --> Node -->  Node.appendChild() on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/